# Como criar um seletor de cidades antes de entrar no site

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

Olá

Estou tentando criar um seletor de cidades para o usuário selecionar a cidade e de acordo com a cidade, ir para a página específica, mas não sei nem como pesquisar sobre isso

Fiz tudo em wordpress, montei um popup e nesse popup coloquei um iframe, onde nesse iframe tem um menu dropdown para selecionar a cidade, porém ao selecionar a cidade, a página fica dentro do iframe

Ou seja, acho que iframe não seja a melhor opção nesse caso.

Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso no wordpress?

Comment: Predente memorizar a cidade por `Cookies` ou direto no `DB`?

Comment: Vc quer que a página que fica dentro do iframe vá para a página principal?

Comment: Coloque na pergunta o código no iframe que você está usando. É preciso saber como vc está fazendo isso, senão não tem como adivinhar.

Comment: não pretendo memorizar, seria apenas mesmo um link para ir para a cidade específica, as páginas de cidades estão todas prontas.

o código que estou usando no seletor, é esse
https://pastebin.com/jba0zizG

e inseri um iframe dentro do plugin "Layred Poup" para exibir um iframe dessa página, usando o seguinte código
<iframe src="myURL" width="100%" height="100%" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe > 

me perdoem os erros e etc.. sou novo aqui, não costumo postar em fórums
obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Como você não deu muitos detalhes irei fazer algo básico, mas que irá servir. Basta você adaptar posteriormente.

Nós podemos trabalhar com *Páginas Estáticas* no *WordPress*, isso vai nos permitir criar, alterar ou deletar a página através do painel de administração.

Primeiro iremos criar nosso arquivo na raiz do tema. `wp-content/themes/SEU-TEMA/cities.php`

Dentro desse arquivo iremos adicionar o código abaixo:

```
/**
 * Template Name: Choose City
 */
```

Esse `Template Name` indica para o *WordPress* que esta, é uma página de template. Assim pode podemos escolher no painel de administração.

[image: Painel de administração do WordPress]

No mesmo arquivo, iremos adicionar o código base. Aqui você pode fazer do seu jeito.

Eu peguei um layout para testar: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/8Mlzr . Como é apenas uma demonstração e não há muitos detalhes, irei fazer algo bem básico.

**Código comentado:**

```html
<?php
    /**
     * Template Name: Choose City
     * Layout Author: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/8Mlzr
     */

    ?>
<!DOCTYPE hml>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
        <style>
            @import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,600";
            *,
            *::before,
            *::after {
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            html, body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            }
            a {
            color: #FFF;
            text-decoration: none;
            }
            a:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
            }
            body {
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0;
            font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
            background: #644cad;
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #644cad 0%, #4426a8 100%);
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #644cad 0%, #4426a8 100%);
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #644cad 0%, #4426a8 100%);
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            }
            h2 {
            margin-top: 0px;
            color: #4d5c6e;
            font-weight: 400;
            }
            p {
            color: #72879e;
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 24px;
            }
            .blur {
            -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
            -moz-filter: blur(5px);
            -o-filter: blur(5px);
            -ms-filter: blur(5px);
            filter: blur(5px);
            }
            .flex {
            min-height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            }
            .modalcontainer {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            }
            .modalcontainer.active {
            display: block;
            }
            .modal {
            display: none;
            position: relative;
            width: 600px;
            height: 330px;
            background-color: #FFF;
            overflow: initial;
            opacity:0;
            }
            .modal.active {
            display: block;
            }
            .modal .content {
            padding: 30px;
            }
            .modal .close {
            font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
            cursor: pointer;
            color: #FFF;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 50px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            color: #999;
            font-size: 40px;
            }
            .modal .close span {
            transform: rotate(45deg);
            display: block;
            }
            .modal .buttons {
            width: 600px;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: #FFF;
            }
            .modal .buttons a {
            width: 50%;
            height: 50px;
            line-height: 50px;
            text-align: center;
            float: left;
            background-color: #EEE;
            color: #4d5c6e;
            transition: 0.3s;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-weight: bold;
            }
            .modal .buttons a:hover {
            background-color: #e1e1e1;
            }
            .modal .buttons a:nth-of-type(2) {
            float: right;
            color: #FFF;
            background-color: #00c06d;
            }
            .modal .buttons a:nth-of-type(2):hover {
            background-color: #00a75f;
            }
            .modalbttn {
            background-color: #24252A;
            padding: 12px 25px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
            border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
            border-radius: 4px;
            }
            .modalbttn:hover {
            background-color: #2b2c32;
            }
            .wrapper-dropdown-3 {
            /* Size and position */
            position: relative;
            width: 200px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 10px;
            /* Styles */
            background: #fff;
            border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
            box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(50,50,50,0.1);
            cursor: pointer;
            outline: none;
            }
            .wrapper-dropdown-3:after {
            content: "";
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            position: absolute;
            right: 15px;
            top: 50%;
            margin-top: -3px;
            border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #000 transparent;
            }
            .wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown {
            /* Size & position */
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
            /* Styles */
            background: white;
            border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.17);
            font-weight: normal;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
            -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
            -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
            -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
            transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
            list-style: none;
            /* Hiding */
            opacity: 0;
            pointer-events: none;
            }
            .wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown li a {
            display: block;
            padding: 10px;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #000;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e8ea;
            box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,1);
            -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
            -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
            -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
            transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
            }
            .wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown li i {
            float: right;
            color: inherit;
            }
            .wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown li:first-of-type a {
            border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0;
            }
            .wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown li:last-of-type a {
            border: none;
            border-radius: 0 0 7px 7px;
            }
            /* Hover state */
            .wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown li:hover a {
            background: #f3f8f8;
            }
            /* Active state */
            .wrapper-dropdown-3.active .dropdown {
            opacity: 1;
            pointer-events: auto;
            }
            /* No CSS3 support */
            .no-opacity       .wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown,
            .no-pointerevents .wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown {
            display: none;
            opacity: 1; /* If opacity support but no pointer-events support */
            pointer-events: auto; /* If pointer-events support but no pointer-events support */
            }
            .no-opacity       .wrapper-dropdown-3.active .dropdown,
            .no-pointerevents .wrapper-dropdown-3.active .dropdown {
            display: block;
            }
            .form-control {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 34px;
            padding: 6px 12px;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 1.42857143;
            color: #555;
            background-color: #fff;
            background-image: none;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
            box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="flex">
            <div class="modalcontainer">
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="modal">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h2>Escolha sua cidade</h2>

                            <!-- Captura e exibe o conteúdo da página -->
                            <?php the_post(); the_content(); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>

            /* Captura a instância do LocalStorage ou SessionSotrage, caso não encontre, define nulo */
            const localStorage = window.localStorage || sessionStorage || null;

            /* Caso o valor seja nulo, exibe um erro no Console. */
            if (localStorage == null) {
                throw Error("LocalStorage not found");
            }

            /* Captura o elemento .modalContainer (Overlay) */
            const modalContainer = document.querySelector(".modalcontainer")

            /* Captura o elemento .modal (Onde exibe as cidades) */
            const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");

            /* Captura o select da cidade. (Obrigatório) */
            const city = document.querySelector("#city");

            /* Exibe o modal com uma animação do tipo FadeIn */
            function displayCities() {
                modalContainer.style.display = "block";
                modal.style.display = "block";

                let anim = setInterval( () => {
                    let op = new Number(modal.style.opacity || 0)
                    modal.style.opacity = op+.01
                    modalContainer.style.opacity = op+.01

                    if (op >= 1) {
                        clearInterval(anim)
                    }
                }, 15)

                city.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
                    localStorage.setItem("city", e.target.value)
                    location.href = e.target.value;
                });
            }

            /**
             * (Opcional)
             * Verifica se a cidade já foi definida, caso já tenha sido
             * redireciona o usuário, caso contrário exibe as cidades
             *
             * Caso opte por não utilizar essa função, basta substituir
             * o código abaixo por "displayCities();"
             */
            if (! localStorage.getItem("city") ) {
                displayCities();
            } else {
                location.href = localStorage.getItem("city");
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Para cadastrar as cidades é bem simples. Basta acessar o painel de administração > Páginas > Adicionar Nova

[image: Cadastrando cidades]

Clique na opção `Texto` e utilize o código abaixo como exemplo:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.

    <select id="city" class="form-control" name="city">
<option>Selecione uma cidade</option>
    <option value="https://www.ilhaboipeba.org.br/pousadasmorere.html">Moreré, Ilha de Boipeba (BA)</option>
    <option value="http://loucosporpraia.com.br/praia-de-jericoacoara-ceara/">Praia de Jericoacoara, Jijoca de Jericoacoara (CE)</option>
    <option value="http://www.diariodepernambuco.com.br/app/46,15/2017/02/23/interna_turismo,690904/bainha-do-sancho-em-fernando-de-noronha-ganha-titulo-de-melhor-praia.shtml">Baía do Sancho, Fernando de Noronha (PE)</option>
    <option value="https://viagemeturismo.abril.com.br/atracao/praia-patacho/">Praia do Patacho, São Miguel dos Milagres (AL)</option>
    <option value="https://viagemeturismo.abril.com.br/atracao/baia-dos-porcos/">Baía dos Porcos, Fernando de Noronha (PE)</option>
    <option value="https://www.feriasbrasil.com.br/pe/portodegalinhas/">Porto de Galinhas, Ipojuca (PE)</option>
    <option value="http://www.pipa.com.br/pt-br/">Praia de Pipa, Tibau do Sul (RN)</option>
    <option value="http://www.portalcanoaquebrada.com.br">Canoa Quebrada (CE)</option>
    </select>
```

Para adicionar novas cidades, basta adicionar novos elementos `option` setando no atributo `value`, o link da página.

**Forçando o usuário a escolher a cidade:**

Para forçar o usuário a escolher sua cidade, basta adicionar o código abaixo no seu arquivo onde está o `header`.

```
<script>
    /* Captura a instância do LocalStorage ou SessionSotrage, caso não encontre, define nulo */
    const localStorage = window.localStorage || sessionStorage || null;

    /* Caso o valor seja nulo, exibe um erro no Console. */
    if (localStorage == null) {
        throw Error("LocalStorage not found");
    }

    if (! localStorage.getItem("city") ) {
        /* Adicione aqui o link permanente da página */
        location.href = "https://www.example.com/cities/"
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Vou testar, e retorno aqui.